# How to migrate intranet SharePoint Site Collection http://companyname.sharepoint.com from one tenant to another tenant?

Tags: sharepoint-online, migration

I am working on SharePoint tenant to tenant migration using third party tool.I have intranet Site Collection http://company1.sharepoint.com having data to migrate to new tenant Site Collection http://companyname2.sharepoint.com (already exists in organisation).
Can we have two intranet Site Collections in one tenant?
Can I create new Site Collection in the new tenant and migrate? or Do i need to
just move the data from Site Collection(old tenant) to Site Collection(new tenant).

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can migrate just the data, but that would be considered off topic in StackExchange and you should discuss how to do that with the vendor of the tool you're using.